# Is there any Ropsten (or any other testnet) node with whisper enabled?

Tags: testnets, ropsten, whisper

I am trying the embark framework which has whisper integration. I wanted to deploy the dapp and test it live. If there is one could you let me know the endpoint and port. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out? I am also trying to integrate whisper for my dapp on ropsten, really confused!

Comment: @JarenL at the time of writing there was no public node running whisper. Not aware about now.